# How do I configure auditd to print the ppid name, not just the ppid?

Tags: process, reboot, audit

OS is Debian. I have set up auditd to try and determine what is rebooting a system.

I have the following rule:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/bin/systemctl -k debug_test
```

Creating a rule for `/usr/sbin/reboot` doesn't work, since it's a symlink to `/bin/systemctl`, but this rule works perfectly, it captures every time a reboot command is executed. I can then search for these reboots with command: `ausearch -k debug_test | grep reboot`. (Note the rule key doesn't contain the string "reboot", since that is what I need to grep for)

However, this just prints the ppid of the process responsible, I am looking for the process name of the ppid. Is it possible to configure auditd to log this? Or would I have to write some kind of daemon that logs all pids + process names every 15 seconds or so?

Answer (score 2):

I've been going over the [auditing documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing) some.

`Auditd` doesn't use placeholders like `%{process.value}`. Based on the list of values:

```
uid,  auid,  gid, pid, subj_user, subj_role, subj_type, subj_sen, subj_clr, msgtype,  and  executable  name.
```

I don't believe logging the parent process name directly in the rule key is possible. I think using "executable name" IS the problem you have with `systemctl` & `reboot`.

"You can find the parent process name by using the parent process id (ppid) printed in the audit log." *( which was essentially my first answer, terdon ;-) )*

I've discovered you can use `ausearch` with your original `ppid`'s to find the event where this process was created. It will be logged in the `execve` system call.  That means the `PID`'s are not long gone!

On the same log line as the PPID's, look for `type=EXECVE` and a list of arguments (a0, a1...) which "make" the command used:

```
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1622816736.650:123456): argc=3 a0="sh" a1="-c" a2="reboot"
```

This shows the parent process was a shell (`sh`), using argument `-c` running the command (`reboot`).  Now, `ausearch` and my first suggestion can have a wedding.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Assuming ausearch command outputs lines with the format id=VAL
for ppid_line in $(your_actual_ausearch_command_here); do
    ppid_to_match=$(echo "$ppid_line" | grep -Eo 'id=[0-9]{1,}')

    # Extract the process information and commands
    process_info=$(sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep -i "$ppid_to_match" | grep -Ei 'a0=.*')

    echo "$ppid_to_match is: $process_info"
done

exit 0
```

Your `ausearch` command retrieves the PPID in the form of id=VAL, isolate `id=`, then extract the corresponding information which starts with `a0=`, that lead to the actual command.

Comment: Since OP is tracking reboots, by the time the system has finished rebooting and OP checks the logs to get the process information, the PID isn't going to be relevant to whatever is currently running.

Comment: If they got the number, capture it immediately. `capture=$(commands the number comes out of); ps -p $capture -o comm= >> capture_file; printf " $capture" >> capture_file` Output: `process_name id_num` on each line.

Comment: When I try this, I just get `key=debug_test/%{parent.name}` in the output of ausearch

Comment: @catpants I modified it, it needed `.exe`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately same issue: `key=debug_test/%{parent.exe}`

Comment: @catpants Do over! :-)

Comment: I'm getting no matches for: `ausearch -ts today -p <ppid>`. (replacing the ppid with the ppid shown in the reboot logged by auditd) Do I need a rule for this? Thank you!

Comment: I would have thought having `-S execve` would be what it needed for the log to contain the `$a` output... try `grep` directly on the log file to see if it contains the data, it may be the usage of `ausearch`, which I'm not really familiar with. It can't hurt trying to add a key.  `-k pid`

Comment: Using ausearch, I am able to get the ppid. I then grep `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for that pid, but I get no results (besides the single line that shows `ppid=VAL`)

Comment: @catpants The command gets the PPID number, you all but have it. I've updated the answer.